# McDuff-to-hyperfinite step in Connes' Injectivity $\Rightarrow$ Hyperfiniteness

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In Connes' "Classification of Injective Factors" (1976) the last step in Injectivity $\Rightarrow$ Hyperfiniteness (Thm. 5.1) is the implication 2. $\Rightarrow$ 1., where

1. $N \cong R$,
2. a) $N$ is McDuff (i.e. $N \cong N \bigotimes R$), and

   b) $\forall [\lbrace x_1, ..., x_n \rbrace \subset N, \epsilon > 0]\ \exists [\lbrace z_1, ..., z_n \rbrace \subset R$ and a unitary $U \in N \bigotimes R]$ such that $\lVert x_j\otimes 1 - U(1\otimes z_j)U^{*} \rVert _2 < \epsilon $ for $j=1,...,n$,

where $N$ and $R$ are $\mathrm{II_1}$ factors; $R$ being the hyperfinite one.

(I don't think b) is relevant to my question below)

Connes starts the proof of 2. $\Rightarrow$ 1., with "... let
$(N_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an increasing generating sequence of subfactors of $N$, all isomorphic to $N$, with relative commutant isomorphic to $R$ and giving factorizations $N = N_k \bigotimes N_k^\prime$ ".

I am guessing his subfactors come from continuing to factor $N$ into $N\bigotimes R$, $N\bigotimes R\bigotimes R$, $N\bigotimes R\bigotimes R\bigotimes R$,  etc., and taking in $N$ (images, under these isomorphisms, of)  $N \bigotimes \mathbb{C}1$, $N \bigotimes \mathbb{C}1 \bigotimes \mathbb{C}1$, etc.

But why are these generating for $N$?

Comment: yes, $< \epsilon$, fixed, thanks.

Comment: Presumably you may use 2 b) to show that $1\otimes R$ is dense in $N\otimes R$

Comment: Connes uses the "generating" property to approximate the given $x$'s with $x$'s in one of those "pure $N$" parts of the decomposition $N = N \bigotimes R$, then uses property 2b) (he doesn't break up his 2 into a) and b) btw) to approximate these new $x$'s with $z$'s from the "pure $R$" part, but these $z$'s in $R$ are approximated by a finite-dimensional subfactor and by MvN4 we are done .  He spells out everything else I've seen in this paper, that's why I think it's some easy thing I am overlooking.

Comment: For his subsequent argument, "generating" possibly includes all the unitary conjugates of subfactors of $N$ representable as  $N \bigotimes R$, so that's a lot. Presumably one can show that it's commutant is no bigger than the commutant of the whole $N$.

Comment: If I understand your strategy correct, what you're suggesting doesn't work: you would be identifying $N\otimes R \cong N\otimes R^{\otimes n}$ via an isomorphism $R \cong R^{\otimes n}$ and this will always take $1_R$ to $1_{R} \otimes \dots \otimes 1_R$. So $N\otimes \mathbb C 1$ is identified with $N\otimes \mathbb C1 \otimes \mathbb C1$. What I think Connes has in mind, is to take $F_k \subset R$ matrix subfactors so that $R = F_k \otimes F_k'$ and letting $N_k = N\otimes F_k \subseteq N\otimes R$.

Comment: @Jamie Gabe My suggestion was to iterate $N \cong N \otimes R$ rather than $R \cong R \otimes R$, but no matter -- I think your suggestion works, so unless you see something wrong with it, do you want to submit it as an answer?